# Why is the "Randomize" option missing from my Array modifier (in 2.91)?

Tags: modifiers, documentation

According to the Blender 2.91 Manual, the Array modifier has a "Randomize" option:

[Array Modifier: Randomize](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/modifiers/generate/array.html#randomize)

Mine, however, does not.  Is there something I'm missing?

I am so used to being able to do this easily in C4D and I'm killing myself trying to figure it out in Blender.  Little help!?

Comment: This might help https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/207184/86891

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Randomize function of the Array Modifier is limited to Grease Pencil objects:

[image: Random]

Comment: Ah man, I didn't realize. How do we change this?

Comment: for the moment you need to apply the array then separate then Object > Transform > Randomize Transform , or choose another solution like particles